Replicating a modified object to linked objects?
My workflow uses Duplicate Linked objects. Modifying the mesh automatically updates linked meshes as expected. For clarity, this means creating an object, say a cube, then choosing "Duplicate Linked" so all objects are using the same underlying mesh; modify any of the object's mesh and all other meshes update.
The problem: I now add a bevel modifier to one of the cubes, and also a sphere above it and parent it to the cube. I want to now replicate this changed object to all other objects linked to the cube's mesh.
I can do this manually with this workflow:

Select Hierarchy on the modified object
Duplicate Linked
Copy the position and rotation of the old object to the new one
Delete the old one

This is very tedious. I'd like to write a script that does this. My script isn't working though. It duplicates the cube and positions it, but doesn't have a child sphere and doesn't delete the object being replaced. Any thoughts what's wrong?
# blender script which deeply replicates linked objects
import bpy

# if no selection, bail
source_obj = bpy.context.active_object
if not source_obj:
    print("No active object selected")
    quit()

# set the selection to be objects linked to the active object
bpy.ops.object.select_linked()

# copy the selection to a list (this only copies the parent object references)
selected_objects = list(bpy.context.selected_objects)

# for each object in the selection
for obj in selected_objects:
    # if the object is the active object skip it
    if obj == source_obj:
        continue

    # clear all selections
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="DESELECT")
    # set active object to our source object parent
    source_obj.select_set(True)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = source_obj
    # select the hierarchy of the linked object
    bpy.ops.object.select_hierarchy(extend=True)
    # bpy.ops.outliner.object_operation(type="SELECT_HIERARCHY")
    # duplicate linked active object
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked=True)
    # get the new object
    new_obj = bpy.context.active_object
    # copy the position and rotation of the old parent object to the new parent object
    new_obj.location = obj.location
    new_obj.rotation_euler = obj.rotation_euler
    # copy the parent of the old object to the new object
    new_obj.parent = obj.parent
    # add the new object to the same collection as the linked object
    obj_collection = obj.users_collection[0]
    # delete the old object
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="DESELECT")
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    bpy.ops.object.delete()
```


Hi. The steps you list are unclear. What's the modified object? What's replaced object? How is it replaced? Could you edit the question and state what you want to do clearly? Why are you doing this? What's the context? Can you add some sketches/screenshots illustrating your desired results and the problem?

So you have some objects selected and you want to duplicate the active object with its hierarchy to the positions of the selected objects or something like that?

Yeah, something like that. The only difference is that since "Select Linked" correctly selects all the other meshes, I only select a single object I want replicated. Basically while editing an object in a scene, once I'm done and go back to Object mode, I want to run a script to replicate the active object to all the others.

Wouldn't using collection instances get rid of the problem altogether ? Do you need to be able to modify every instance independently ?

I can use Collection Instances and it was my first thought. My problem with them is that they either create empty nodes on export (if Empty types enabled) or they get removed entirely and the whole thing gets flattened with no hierarchy. Because this is for a game, and we need the hierarchy for culling efficiently, don't want the extra empty transform, and don't want to write a custom exporter, we are currently looking at the workflow mentioned in the question.
